# Excel - Ranking of date & time, rank by day

Tags: excel, date, time, ranking

Please see list of date and times in cells:

[image: List of dates and times]

I would like to find the ranking of the cell's date and time according to what day it falls on.
 So in this example "14/12/2023 09:06" would rank 1, "14/12/2023 13:04" would rank 2. "15/12/2023 08:59" would rank 1, "15/12/2023 13:28" would rank 2. And finally, "19/12/2023 10:49" would rank 1, "19/12/2023 13:03" would rank 2. Any ideas on how to retrieve these rankings based on the day?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by "rank based on day it falls on"? Do you mean a day of the month, day of the week, or day of the year? Please give more details on what algorithm you try to implement.

I suspect that what you really try to do is just sort by time from oldest to newest but I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, so the ranking will reset if the row below is a different day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try-

```
=XMATCH(A1,SORT(FILTER($A$1:$A$6,($A$1:$A$6>=INT(A1)+TIME(0,0,1))*($A$1:$A$6<=INT(A1)+TIME(23,59,59)))),1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because dates are integers and times are decimals, count same integers values:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2;">="&INT(A2);$A$2:A2;"<"&(INT(A2)+1))
```

[image]

Note this formula will work only if your data is sorted as shown in your image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `MMULT()`

[image]

---

```
 =LET(a, A2:A7, b, ROW(a), MMULT((b>=TOROW(b))*(INT(a)=TOROW(INT(a))),b^0))
```

---